# The time complexity of Iterator() in java

Tags: java, iterator

I am new to Java. I have a question about the time complexity of java iterator().

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

Iterator<Integer> iter = set.iterator(); ==> (2)
```

I wanna know what is the time complexity of step 2? It is const time **O(1)** or it depends on the size of set?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `iterator()` is constant time. It is a method call that returns an `Iterator` instance on the collection you are calling on. Actually iterating through the collection using the iterator using `while (hasNext())` will be O(n)

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `iterator()` method, you're not looping anywhere. This method just returns an iterator over the elements and that time is constant, and thus you don't calculate time-complexity for this.

You calculate the time-complexity wherever you're accessing the elements from a group of elements. *For example,* when you access the elements like this:

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
   Object element = iterator.next();
}
```

This is where you can calculate the time complexity, and in this case it will be `O(n)`.