# Why isn't TreeSet's first method implemented in O(1) time?

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, treeset

My understanding of`TreeSet`'s `first()` method is that it will take `O(log n)` based of the explanation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214670/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-ordered-operations-in-treeset) answer.

The explanation in that answer says that for it to be `o(1)` we would need to maintain a pointer to the first element in the `TreeSet` which would add a constant time to every operation. However, doesn't Java already maintain such a pointer since the `iterator()` method of a collection must be `O(1)`? i.e couldn't we just instantiate the iterator in `O(1)` and get the first element using `next()` in constant time?

Comment: Who said `next()` was constant time?

Comment: And who says that `iterator()` needs to be `O(1)`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559839/big-o-summary-for-java-collections-framework-implementations tells you that `next()` is `O(n)` btw.

Comment: @GhostCat [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371854/the-time-complexity-of-iterator-in-java) led me to believe that iterator() should be O(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iterator()` returns an object that implements the Iterator interface. This *can* be accomplished in constant time, of course.

E. g. the iterator might manage a pointer to the current element. At the beginning this pointer might be `null`, so that the first call of `hasNext()` would have to walk down the tree to the first element, which should have a complexity of O(log n).